# How to create array in php to request for SOAPclient of complexType?

Tags: php, soap-client

How to create an array in php, to pass request for this complexType?

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="path" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:element name="Security">
<xsd:complexType>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:complexType name="UsernameTokenType">
<xsd:sequence><xsd:element name="Username" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="Password" type="PasswordType"/>
</xsd:sequence></xsd:complexType><xsd:complexType name="PasswordType">
<xsd:simpleContent>
<xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
<xsd:attribute name="partyType" type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
</xsd:extension>
</xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Please do try writting some code yourself first and then posting it when you still have issues.